# Magick++ Compressing and Decompressing files

Tags: image, imagemagick, compression, magick++

I've found the compressType()-Method of the Image class in ImageMagick Magick++.
I searched for examples how to use it, but there isn't much of information about that.

Can someone give me an example of how to open a compressed file and how to compress & save an image?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Usage:

Magick::Image.compressType(CompressionType)

The list of available compression types:
http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Enumerations.html#CompressionType

Example:

```
#include "Magick++.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    Magick::Image image;
    try{
        image.read("image.jpg");
        image.compressType(JPEGCompression);
        image.write("image.jpg");
    catch(Magick::Exception &error_)
    {std::cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << std::endl;}
}
```

If the compression type specified is incompatable with the image, ImageMagick selects a compression type compatable with the image type.
BTW, these compression types and the method compressType are for expressing the desired compression type when encoding an image (Not for adding the image to an archive). Note, I haven't compiled/tested the above example.